# Install Tensorflow on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04

I have tried to install Tensorflow on Ubuntu 16.04 but

```
Collecting tensorflow==0.7.1 from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.7.1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
  Using cached https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.7.1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy>=1.8.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow==0.7.1)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.10.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensCollecting tensorflow==0.7.1 from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.7.1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
  Using cached https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.7.1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy>=1.8.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow==0.7.1)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.10.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow==0.7.1)
Requirement already up-to-date: protobuf==3.0.0b2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow==0.7.1)
Requirement already up-to-date: wheel in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow==0.7.1)
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from protobuf==3.0.0b2->tensorflow==0.7.1)
Installing collected packages: tensorflow
  Found existing installation: tensorflow 0.7.1
    Uninstalling tensorflow-0.7.1:
      Successfully uninstalled tensorflow-0.7.1
Successfully installed tensorflow-0.7.1
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
milenko@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~$ python
Python 2.7.11 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
orflow==0.7.1)
```

I have used sudo -H ,so I do not understand why this happens.
My Python installations

```
readlink -f $(which python) | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo -n "%: "; % -V'
/home/milenko/miniconda2/bin/python2.7: Python 2.7.11 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
```

Comment: You probably have more than one Python installation -- the default one, and Anaconda version, try to do `/usr/bin/python` or `/usr/local/bin/python` instead of `python`

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Yes,I nave miniconda installed.

Comment: So I guess one of them has `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` in `sys.path` and the other one doesn't, hence the other one doesn't see `tensorflow`

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov bash: cd: /usr/local/bin/python: No such file or directo

Comment: Anaconda uses it's own paths for packages so installation of TensorFlow for Anaconda is slightly different, there are a few answered questions about it on "[tensorflow] anaconda"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me with [this tutorial.](https://alliseesolutions.wordpress.com/2016/09/08/install-gpu-tensorflow-from-sources-w-ubuntu-16-04-and-cuda-8-0-rc/)

I used Anaconda 2.7 version and created a virtual environment (feel free to use py3 & python=3.5) :

```
conda create --name py2 python=2.7 anaconda
```

Don't forget to activate it before installation (and use afterwards !) :

```
source activate py2
```

And I would advise to upgrade scikit-learn and libgcc:

```
conda upgrade scikit-learn libgcc
```

Then follow the linked tutorial.

I think this has changed quite a lot since you asked 5 months ago, but I hope it will help people stumbling upon this post. In your case I suppose it really was a conflict between the miniconda and system python distributions.